# How to extract value from GET request in karate

Tags: karate

I am new to REST and Karate testing. Our project uses Karate for service virtualization during integration tests. I am calling a RESTful GET API with the following url structure:
http://localhost:8080/SampleService/v1/person/{personId}/personAssetRelationships

Below is the Scenario I have written

```
#Scenario to get all assets a person was ever assigned
Scenario:
pathMatches(/SampleService/v1/person/{personId}/personAssetRelationships) &&
methodId('get')

* def responseStatus = 200
* def response = 
"""
[
  {
    "personId": "13",
    "assetIdentifier": "21324",
    "assignedDate": "2020-11-22",
    "returnedDate": "9999-12-31",
    "replacedAssetIdentifier": null
  }
]
"""
```

This works during my integration test. The only concern is that the personId in my response is static. I want to be able to use the personId that is passed in the request path in my response. I am not sure how a I can do that. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Won't `pathParams.personId` work, read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#pathparams

```
"personId": "#(pathParams.personId)",
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly!
I was doing an eval(path) because I found some examples of eval(request) for POST functions but that did not work.